# How to get Price Tier for InApp Purchase dynamically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I am having an app in which I am using 5 Consumable In App Purchases.

There are InApp Price on the buttons.

**-** I don't want to set the value of In App (e.g. $0.99,$1.99 and so on...) statically.

**-** I want the Price on my buttons dynamically that is actually on iTunes store.

Is it possible to get the Price Tier from iTunes's InApp and display that?

Comment: Please read the [In-App Purchase Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267). It covers all of this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You request the list of available `SKProduct`s with:

```
self.productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:self.productIdentifiers];
self.productsRequest.delegate = self;
[self.productsRequest start];
```

You need implement [`SKProductsRequestDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skproductsrequestdelegate?language=objc). This has one method that returns you an array with `SKProduct`s. in the class that has the above code.

Then you'll need a method like this:

```
- (NSString*)localizedFormattedPrice:(SKProduct*)product
{
    NSString*          formattedString;
    NSNumberFormatter* numberFormatter;

    numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [numberFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    [numberFormatter setLocale:product.priceLocale];

    formattedString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:@(product.price)];

    return formattedString;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I will try this and let u know. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @meaning-matters how can cast SKProductsRequest to SKProduct ?

Comment: @Rushi It's not casting but requesting. See the extended answer above,

Answer (score 2):

```
NSNumberFormatter * _priceFormatter;

_priceFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[_priceFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
[_priceFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

[_priceFormatter setLocale:product.priceLocale];
priceLabel.text = [_priceFormatter stringFromNumber:product.price];
```

Comment: @ushan37: Ok, I will check and let u know. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I want the price tier on my labels initially when the app launches. Means when I open the view as shown above the Price tier for that product ids should be there even if I didn't press those buttons. Is it possible to get that? Because delegate methods for inapp will only get called if I pressed the inapp purchase button? Waiting for your reply.

Comment: Go through this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial , it covers all the basics of in-app purchasing. You can request for the products list using SKProductsRequest. And you can do it anywhere in your code. I suggest you to go through this tutorial